# Entity Framework query with *sql* subquery

Tags: c#, .net, sql, entity-framework, ef-code-first

In short: can I use a literal SQL subquery somehow in the entity model without using database views?

Context: I have a bunch of ADO.NET queries that result in C# objects.  These objects correspond directly to the query shape; i.e. I can do [`ObjectContext.Translate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466384) to extract them from the `SqlDataReader`.  There are lots of these queries, many quite complex, and some of which use features the entity framework doesn't support (while loops, CTE's, hierarchyids, etc.) - converting these (legacy) queries to LINQ isn't feasible.

However, I'd really like to be able wrap these results and add some custom filtering on the C# side of things: things like sorting, filtering, paging etc.  I could convert each and every query into a view (or stored procedure) and map these, but that's a hassle and a maintenance nightmare - but in principle EF can be used with "opaque" SQL queries by that route.

Can I somehow use subqueries written in SQL with the entity model?  An `ObjectContext.Translate` that returns an `IQueryable` rather than an `IEnumerable` would be ideal, but not necessary: the vast majority of queries are compile-time constants, so some form of pre-processing is possible.

***Edit:*** I'm looking for something returning an `IQueryable` so I can add filters/sorting client side but have them executed on the DB (as usual).  I'm using Entity Framework code-first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the `DefiningQuery` property of an EntitySet to some literal SQL. These are more or less equivalent to a SQL view. Does that solve your issue?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc982038.aspx

Comment: That looks good!  However, I notice I neglected to mention I'm already using code-first and you can't mix code first with model-first in the same assembly; so this solution looks hard to use, unfortunately.

Comment: Marking as answer: it's probably the best possible solution, even though it's far from ideal.  Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

If your SQL query is giving a result with the same structure  as of the entity class, you can use the `DbContext.SqlQuery`

```
 var customer=context.Database.
         SqlQuery<Customer>("SELECT ID,NAME from CUSTOMER WHERE TYPE IN 
                     (SELECT TYPEID FROM IMPORTANT_TYPE)");
```

Assuming `context` is your DBContext class object

Comment: No, this won't work: `SqlQuery` returns an `IEnumerable`; so if I try to compose the result with further filtering, I'll be doing that client-side (and generally be retrieving LOTS of excess data and thus being slow).